# set Kendo FlatColorPicker default value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

How do i go about setting the Kendo FlatColorPicker default value using MVC with either ViewBag or a variable?

```
@{
    var iconColor = ViewBag.FaviconColor;
}
@(Html.Kendo().FlatColorPicker()
    .Name("faviconColor")
    .Value(iconColor) 
    .Events(events => events
    .Change("ColorChange"))
)
```

I tried with

```
.Value("ViewBag.FaviconColor")
.Value("@ViewBag.FaviconColor")
.Value(ViewBag.FaviconColor)
.Value(@ViewBag.FaviconColor)
```

I get a javascript error when i try to do this, there has to be a way.

Comment: what is error ?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Cannot parse color: viewbag.faviconcolor